# Get XML from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have an `NSString` and I want to get `XML` from it. I have my own XML parser written which can convert the `XML` and give me the desired values. Just the way I can get a dictionary from a string I want a way to get XML from a string.

**Input:** 
`"<message from='eddc6896' to='70b85d94'</message>"`

**Output Required:**
`<message from='eddc6896' to='70b85d94'
</message>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want a "prettyPrinted" equivalent? Adding "\n" where it's needed?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your Q: If you have your own XML parser, which can convert the values … Why isn't able to store that values into a dictionary.

However, you can simply use the built-in XML parser, which creates an XML document you can send queries to:

```
NSError *error;
NSXMLDocument *doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:theString options:0 error:&error];
```

To get the root element, simply use `-rootElement`.